# What is pulse train filter?

Tags: matlab, filters, kalman-filters, filtering, control-systems

I have recently seen some code written in modelling tool like Simulink, ASCET which uses PT1 filter? Why do we use a pulse train filter? What is the difference between FIR, IIR, Chebyschev, Butterworth and a Pulse Train filter? When a signal continuous passes through a pulse train what happens?

Comment: RTFM? http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pulstran.html

Comment: HI.  I've heard of "time- and freq-domain pulse trains" but not a "pulse train filter".  You need to define what you mean by a pulse train filter, or give a web link where we can figure out what you're talking about.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input. But I'm talking about the one in this link https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PT1-Glied

Comment: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PT2-Glied